# Method Issue On My MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods, bootstrapping

I am just making my own MVC. However, I've encountered a problem. As you know before, if there is a URL like "www.site.com/users/star", "users" is defined as a controller and "star" is defined as a method in MVC style. So, I assume that I want to make a profile page for users. I need a url such as "www.site.com/user/{username}". In this case, username is being evaluated as a method, but it must not be. It is just user's name. How can I prevent this complexity?

Here is my bootstrap.php:
http://tinypaste.com/75cd8487

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use a real MVC engine. Why cause so much trouble for yourself? There are so many free frameworks to use I can't imagine why you would want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @spinon For practice and/or the experience. You'd be surprised how much faster you can pick up X-Framework's bootstrap and instantly identity with their solutions to the same problem.

Comment: a router might replace "user/" with "user/view/" before the interpreting of the request begins. this way you second argument could be the id instead of the method. this of course limits the user controller to one method unless you get really complicated with the routing, so you may want to consider using the full path "user/view/id".

Comment: @spinon I have used real MVC engine such as Codeigniter, but i cannot access everything entirely beacuse of lack of documentation about CI and I had been trouble with its theme engine. and then I decided to make my own MVC engine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A lot of frameworks have the concept of routes. With routes, the URL is not the concrete definition of the controller/action. You can specify a route like `'users/*'` and have it point to the users controller and view action. Then, it's up to the controller to deal with the different params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different URL:

```
www.site.com/user/view/{username}
```

Now, `view` is the method, which would get passed the `{username}` parameter.

Comment: I'll try this way. Thanks! Otherwise, I am going to create a router as other friends say before.

Answer (score 0):

nickb has right but you can create a reroute mechanizm which will reroute these kind of request (no action method found in controller 'user') in the background (without client redirect) to a controller (user) method (info, view etc.).